# Maven: trigger task to upload dependency into Nexus if dependency is not there at the build time

Tags: maven-2, dependency-management, nexus

I have Maven2 project. This project have 1 internal dependency which stored in internal (for our company) Sonatype Nexus. I setup the dependency version in pom.xml as parameter which I provide via Jenkins.

Sometimes I do not have proper dependency version in Nexus so my build can fail on donwload dependency step. I want to add ability to trigger special task (script) if dependency is not found to upload this dependency into Nexus and continue the build.

Can I do so?

I think about fake build for version exists always in Nexus which will check if given version is in Nexus, upload it and launch real build. But such way looks terrible.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by `Sometimes I do not have proper dependency version in Nexus so my build can fail on donwload dependency step` ?

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need to upload anything. You just need to access Nexus via the public group and the download from the Central repository, that is part of that group will happen automatically.